# Can an ASP.NET ASPX Page be Processed From a Source that is not the File System?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to execute a full ASPX source file where the page source is from a string/database/resource and not a file on the file system?  It's straightfoward to render dynamic content/images/etc using HTTP Handlers and Modules and writing to the Response, but there doesn't seem to be a way to execute/compile ASPX source without a file on the file system.  For example:

- HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute() overloads require a path to a file
- System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager can only create from a virtual path

The goal is to be able to execute a string source like the following from a Handler/Module/ViewEngine and not require a file on the file system (but get the source from another location):

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>ListView Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h3>ListView Example</h3>
<asp:ListView ID="List" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductDataSource">
<LayoutTemplate><ol><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder></ol></LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate><li><%# Eval("ProductName") %></li></ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="ProductDataSource" runat="server"DataFile="~/App_Data/Northwind.mdb"SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductName], [QuantityPerUnit], [UnitPrice], [CategoryName] FROM [Alphabetical List of Products]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(NOTE: The sample above is just a simple example, but shows using server controls, data binding syntax, a master page and possible user control declarations in page directives, etc...)

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you need a [virtual path provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx). It allows you to store the ASPX and codebehind in different media - RDBMS, xml file etc.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Check the post by [korchev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154117#154279) using virtualpathprovider, which is more suited for this scenario.

Can you use a dummy file with a place holder **literal** control and replace the literal control with the actual source?

These might not be useful but posting couple of links I found:

[Loading an ASP.NET Page Class dynamically in an HttpHandler](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/120530.aspx)

[How To: Dynamically Load A Page For Processing](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2007/07/06/how-to-dynamically-load-a-page-for-processing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I knew that SharePoint Server used to keep the ASPX pages in the database and not on the file system. Details, however, I do not hold.